# Google+ like border

Tags: javascript, css, animation, google-plus

I want to understand how Google+'s stream items border-left works? Can every body explain it or suggest any link and/or article?

More: When you focus on a stream, you'll see that the left-border of stream gone to blue, and when you focus on another stream, the border will animate to new focused item.

1. focus on element a
2. a's left-border gone to blue
3. focus on element b
4. the blue-border animate to element b's left-border

Thanks to any suggestion.

Comment: Just look at the HTML/CSS/JS source on that page. It's all there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one if you don't want to use jQuery and only target the latest browsers.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/9UUb9/

HTML:

```
<div id="posts-frame">
    <div id="highlight"></div>
    <ul id="posts">
        <li class="post">post one</li>
        <li class="post">post two</li>
        <li class="post">post three</li>
        <li class="post">post four</li>
    <ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#highlight {
    border-left: 1px solid #4D90F0;    
    height: 0;
    margin-left: 1px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    transition:             top 200ms ease, height 200ms ease;
        -moz-transition:    top 200ms ease, height 200ms ease;
        -ms-transition:     top 200ms ease, height 200ms ease;
        -o-transition:      top 200ms ease, height 200ms ease;
        -webkit-transition: top 200ms ease, height 200ms ease;
}

.post {
    border: 1px solid lightgray;
    display: block;
    height: 45px;
    padding-left: 4px;
}

.post:nth-child( 2 ) {
    height: 70px;    
}

#posts {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;  
    width: 400px;
}

#posts-frame {
    position: relative;       
}
```

Script:

```
function selectPost( event ) {

    var highlight = document.getElementById( 'highlight' );
    highlight.style.height = event.target.clientHeight + 'px';
    highlight.style.top = ( event.target.offsetTop + 1 ) + 'px';

};

document.getElementById( 'posts' ).addEventListener( 'click', selectPost, false);
```

Answer (score 5):

there you go: http://dev.pierre-cholhot.com/gplus-border.html

Comment: +1, for proving I am right ;) And for quick prototypes building skills. :)

Comment: it took me a bit more than 3 min :p i started coding it before seeing your post :D

Comment: Ernest and Pierre: Thank you for example and help, best regards

Answer (score 1):

If you look at HTML and CSS code, you will see that blue border is defined by `hr` CSS class. When you click specific stream post, JavaScript will add `hr` class to this `<div>`. 
Here comes the fun part. When you click on another `<div>` few things will happen:

- `hr` class will be removed from previous stream post
- A new `<div>` will added to the bottom of a page, it looks like this:

`<div class="rh kA" style="left: 0px, top: 73px, width: 572px, height: 318px;"></div>`

- So this newly created div tag will have the position and size of previous... em... div.
- JavaScript is now in control, changing the `top` CSS property, until it will match position of currently clicked post. The height of div is also changed. This part gives you "animation".
- `hr` class is now added to new (clicked) stream post.
- The div that was responsible for animation is deleted from DOM (or hidden).

Of course this all may be wrong, I just know it from playing with Firebug for a while, and so I advise it to you :)

Comment: I think same you too. Thanks to explain. But @Pierre's provided example (http://dev.pierre-cholhot.com/gplus-border.html) is more pretty and helpful so I should accept that. Thanks again

Comment: @Javad_Amiry Yes you should. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably using CSS transitions and the :focus pseudo-class.

Comment: It seems a javascript and an absolute `div` positioned on the left of item! I have some idea to implementing it, but I'm searching for more data and/or experience

Answer (score 0):

Google+ adds the blue border on selected posts by listening for clicks within the outer div. When a click happens the highlight class is removed from the previously highlighted item and added to the current item. The class will add a border width/color/style to the side you want highlighted.

Comment: I know what are you talking about, but in this way, how to animate the border? when you focus-a => focus-b, the border animate from element a to element b

Comment: It's not just removed and added. There is some kind of transition involved, so the marker is _sliding_ up or down.